# Need better terminology for 'Save Form' and 'Submit Form'

Tags: forms, terminology

It is a Registration page for a Hackathon event. Please have a look at the wireframe below.
[image]
Team leads can register there team and save the form before the final submission. The "Save changes" button helps to save any changes made in the form. User can save multiple time before the final submission. The Submit button is too mechanical, can we have a better terminology to humanise the tool? 
Many people are suggesting "Updated Changes" instead of "Save Changes". Please give your view on that. And some suggest "Done! Ready to Rumble" instead for "Submit"
Feel free to give new ideas.

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you change the the button "save changes" to "save for later" because right now, save changes and submit are very similar, other than one is heavy which leans the user towards that. Also, instead of submit, say something along the lines of "Add your team and be ready to compete." Try to stay away from ambiguous button labels. Submit is ok, but doesn't really clarify what the user is trying to do.

Comment: Could you simply remove the Save changes button and just save anyway? In that way there would be only 1 button left, and it's meaning would be clear. In that scenario you could change it to something less formal such as "ready to rumble", or "let's rock 'n' roll" without creating confusion.

Comment: I'm not too sure that's a good idea @BartGijssens. There could be some scenarios where someone will want to submit it because they know details (and don't have to have another hidden step), or want to save it for later because they don't know their full team's details.

Comment: For better experience "auto save" would be ideal option to save changes instantly & show draft saved info at the bottom. Now all you need is Submit button.

Answer (score 2):

"Updated Changes"? That doesn't even make sense in English. "Update Changes" does not either. Save changes is perfectly fine here and if you're still worried about humanising the page, you can always seek to crowd test *"Save Draft"*.

Submit does sound a bit formal, but it's not exactly going to turn people away. Perhaps you can try "apply" or "Enrol [this team]" (where [this team] can be left out or kept in, dependant on user tests).

"Done! Ready to rumble" sounds a bit try-hard and long to me.

*Form team, start, Ready? Fight!, Ready(), etc;* A compiled list of some *fun* words to look at.

Answer (score 1):

"Finish Registration" or "Confirm Registration" will do the job because they both show explicitly the action that matters to te user. 
The user wants to register his team, submitting the form is just a medium to do that, not the final goal.

For saving I would use "Save progress" with the same logic: trying to be as explicit as possible minifying the chances of users getting confused.